# viewPager.setPageTransformer slows down the viewPager scrolling

Tags: android, performance, gridview, scroll, android-viewpager

Please anyone help me.
when i add vp1.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer()); to my Viewpager then viewpager getting slow scroll.
if i remove animation it works fine...

And when i scroll to the next page of viewPager means next Fragment then in that Fragment GridView not scrolls.

Here is the code...

```
vp1 = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp1);
vp1.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

    int offScreen = 5;
    vp1.setOffscreenPageLimit(offScreen);

    postion = postion - 1;


        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());
        vp1.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        int number = adapter.getCount();
        vp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        offScreen = number - 1;
        vp1.setCurrentItem(postion, true);
```

Bassically it kills the functionality of view....

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with setPageTransformer.  Did you ever find a solution?